# "No mapping data was returned from the server" in web api vs2013?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I created new web api mvc4 project in vs2013.
I run it in Page Inspector but it won't open and reported these warning:
No mapping data was returned from the server.

I found a solution in stackoverflow here:
[No mapping data was returned from the server after installing ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350050/no-mapping-data-was-returned-from-the-server-after-installing-asp-net-and-web-to)

But I can't find

```
<map id="surfer" name="surfer">
   <area shape="poly" coords="0,23,30,13,40,3,64,5,69,19,86,23,98,30,99,51,72,63,68,83,41,83,38,67,1,65" alt="&%#&#064;?!">
</map>
```

as it suggested.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Comment default.aspx file part-by-part and try to run it each time to find out what causes the problem. Even simple "view in browser" should do the trick if removing parts of your file forces you to add changes in your code-behind.

In my case it was an "OnClick=" property calling a non-existing code-behind funtion.